# How to send msg in scripts that locates without scripts dir in hubot?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot

I'm beginner at node.js.
I want to do that when hubot hear expected message, evaluate and execute script that is not exist in scripts dir.

I wrote code below code, but I cannot send msg.

Error msg

```
[Thu Feb 16 2017 20:22:34 GMT+0900 (JST)] ERROR ReferenceError: msg is not defined
```

Where should I fix it to define msg?

hubot_dir/scripts/load_test.coffee

```
path = require('path')

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear /loadscript/i, (msg) ->
    script_name = "dynamictest.coffee"
    script_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, "../dynamicscripts")
    dynamictest = require(script_dir + "/" + script_name)
    robot.loadFile(script_dir, script_name)
    robot.emit "dynamic", {
      robot: robot,
      msg: msg
    }
    delete require.cache[script_dir + "/" + script_name]
```

hubot_dir/dynamicscripts/dynamictest.coffee

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.on "dynamic" , (dynamic) ->
    robot.logger.info "output log"
    msg.send "test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `robot.emit`, you are passing an object that *contains* the variable that you call msg (though the name is entirely arbitrary). This object is passed as the parameter named `dynamic`, therefore, in order to reference `msg`, you need to refer to it as `dynamic.msg`:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.on "dynamic" , (dynamic) ->
    robot.logger.info "output log"
    dynamic.msg.send "test"
```

I should point out, however, that with the way your `loadscript` function is written, it will load an additional instance of dynamicscript.coffee every time you call it. For example, the first time you call `loadscript`, it will load the second file and send back 'test'. The second time, it will load the second file yet again, and you will get two responses that say 'test'. On the third time it will load again and you will receive three messages, etc.